# Unable to download oxford_iiit_pet dataset in Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
dataset, info = tfds.load('oxford_iiit_pet:3.*.*', with_info=True)
```

This keeps giving me the following error.

```
2021-02-28 18:33:21.502899: E tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/curl_http_request.cc:614] The transmission  of request 0x55772dd20f40 (URI: http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token) has been stuck at 0 of 0 bytes for 61 seconds and will be aborted. CURL timing information: lookup time: 4.4e-05 (No error), connect time: 0 (No error), pre-transfer time: 0 (No error), start-transfer time: 0 (No error)
```

Version details

```
tensorflow : 2.4.1
tensorflow_datasets : 4.2.0
```

Comment: Could you update to tfds-nightly build once and check? They change checksum's sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to download it. It may cause package issues in yours case. In my case,

```
tensorflow : 2.4.1
tensorflow_datasets : 4.2.0

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds


>>> dataset, info = tfds.load('oxford_iiit_pet:3.*.*', with_info=True)
Downloading and preparing dataset Unknown size (download: Unknown size, generated: Unknown size, total: Unknown size) to C:\Users\innat\tensorflow_datasets\oxford_iiit_pet\3.2.0...
Dl Completed...:  50%|████████████████████████████████                                | 1/2 [05:15<02:54, 174.64s/ url]
Dl Size...:  14%|████████▉                                                         | 105/773 [05:15<33:34,  3.02s/ MiB]
Extraction completed...:   0%|                                                                | 0/1 [05:15<?, ? file/s]
```

Ongoing...It was asked before, [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues/1978). It should fix by now.

Comment: I am using the same versions as above. Still getting the error.
(I have updated it in the question)

From the shared link,
Tried installing tfds-nightly.
Tried manual downloading using tensorflow_datasets.scripts.download_and_prepare.

Still error persists.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't use `tfds-nightly`.